# When is a $2k+1$ component system better than a $2k-1$ component system?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> A communication system consists of $n$ components, each of which will, independently, function with probability $p$. The total system will be able to operate effectively if at least one-half of its components function.
>
> **Question:**
> In general, when is a $2k+1$ component system better than a $2k-1$ component system?

I can't able to figure out how I can solve this problem. Please help me to solve the problem with details.

Answer (score 2):

The number of functioning components follows a binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p.$ Let $X$ be the binomial random variable for the first $\color{red}{2k-1}$ components.

A $2k+1$ component system will operate effectively if $X\geq \frac{2k+1}{2}$ and the $2k-1$ component system will function effectively if $X\geq \frac{2k-1}{2}.$

Then $$ (\star)\space\space \space P_{2k+1}(\text{at least $\frac{2k+1}{2}$ effective components})$$
$$=P_{2k+1}(\text{at least k+1 effective components})$$
$$=P(X\geq k+1)+P(X=k-1)p^{2}+P(X=k)(1-(1-p)^{2})$$

---

Note that in the case above we have $2k+1$ components. Then:

- For $X\geq k+1,$ we have at least $k+1$ working components (out of $2k-1$)
- If $X=k-1$, so $k-1$ components out of $2k-1$ are working effectively so we want the next two components to function effectively too! (Making a total of $2k+1$ components so we multiply the probability by $p^2$)
- If $X=k$, this means that $k$ out of $2k-1$ components are working effectively, so $\color{blue}{\text{at least one of the two}}$ remaining two components (since total number of components is $2k-1+\color{blue}{2}=2k+1$) must function. So we multiply the probability by $P(\text{at least one component is functioning})=1-P(\text{neither component functioning})=1-(1-p)^{2}.$

---

$$(\star\star)\space\space\space P_{2k-1}(\text{at least $\frac{2k-1}{2}$ effective components})=P_{2k-1}(\text{at least k effective components})$$
$$=P(X=k)+P(X\geq k+1).$$

Now you want to find $p$ such that $$(\star)>(\star\star)$$

where $X \sim Bin(2k-1,p).$

---

$$(\star)-(\star\star)>0$$
$$\implies P(X=k-1)p^{2}+P(X=k)(1-(1-p)^{2})-P(X=k)>0$$
$$P(X=k-1)p^{2}-(1-p)^{2}P(X=k)>0$$
$${2k-1 \choose k-1}p^{k-1}(1-p)^{k}p^{2}-{2k-1 \choose k}p^{k}(1-p)^{k-1}(1-p)^{2}$$
$$={2k-1 \choose k} p^{k-1}(1-p)^{k}[p^{2}-p(1-p)]$$
$$={2k-1 \choose k} p^{k-1}(1-p)^{k}[p(2p-1)]>0$$

Hence $$p>\frac{1}{2}.$$

Note that ${2k-1 \choose k-1}={2k-1 \choose k}$.

Comment: Thank you for your help. You have mentioned above that for X≥k+1, we have at least k+1 working components (out of 2k−1). Why out of 2k-1 instead of 2k+1? Could you clarify this point? Also as we are concerned about X>=k+1, then why are we concerning about X=k-1 and X=k in case of P(at least k+1 effective components)?

Comment: You're welcome. Since we have defined $$  be the binomial random variable for the first $\text{color}{2−1}$ components, then there are $2k-1$  components instead of $2k+1$, which makes the calculation easier. If instead you defined two random variables, one with $2k+1$ components and another with $2k-1$, then the calculation will be more difficult. Since $X$ has $2k-1$ components, for the second probability we don't change anything (since we have already $2k-1$ components). But for the first there are $2k+1$ components, so we need to take into account for an extra $2$ components.

Comment: Oh, now I understand. Thank you so much.